Is it possible to walk/climb to the outer side of Sigil?
Sigil is described as a ring-shaped city with all of its life happening on the interior part of the ring. If you walk along the "large diameter", you will just traverse the city and return to where you started (assuming it's possible to navigate through the streets to construct such a path etc.). However, if you walk across, you should in theory end up at the edge of the city. What happens then? Can you walk over the outer surface of Sigil or do you just fall?


It's very possible to start inside Sigil and climb to the outside, but you won't like what happens next.

Along with "up and down" is the question of "inside and outside." It's quite a question, too. Nobody's ever seen the outside of Sigil because there may not even be an "outside." The edges of the ring are all solidly lined by buildings with no windows or doors on their backs. 'Course, a cutter could get himself up on the roof to take a look. Those that've tried it'll tell a body, "There's nothing to see," and they really do mean "nothing" - not emptiness, not a vacuum, just nothing. That matches what flyers say lies beyond the ring:
nothingness.
Humans being a particularly curious type, it's natural that some of the barmies have tried stepping off into the nothingness. Everybody who does so just vanishes. It's said that a few are seen again, too. Apparently, crossing that border hurls a sod into a random plane. Considering the conditions of some of these destinations, it's no surprise that only a few make it back.
-- "Describing Sigil: Up And Down", Sigil And Beyond p.59, emphasis mine

This is what the DM got to work with - no table of random planar destinations (though if I recall correctly there was one in the 2nd-ed DM's guide already) and no greater details about exactly how Sigil's border works.
Yes, there's that lovely concept piece you've posted of Sigil as seen from outside. The boxed set has views of "Sigil from outside" as well, a ring on the spire of the Outlands/Concordant Opposition. But it's also very clear that you can't get inside Sigil by physically traversing that distance, and of course trying to teleport based on your line of sight doesn't work either, since Sigil portals are the only way into Sigil:

This is important: There's no way to walk from the Outlands, or anywhere else for that matter, into Sigil. The Cage can be reached ONLY through the many doors that open onto its streets.
-- "The Outlands", Sigil And Beyond p.22, emphasis original

And again, once you're in Sigil there is no outside. Existence ends at the edge of the roof - you can't even lean out to look down at those windowless back walls because that's past the edge of the roof.
But if a rooftop chase happens and you find yourself cornered against the edge of Sigil, well, you're not really cornered. Is it worth taking the chance?

About a third of the planes are survivable without major precautions. Although most commoners have simply no way to get back in Sigil ever, they will likely need to start a new life.

@GraySheep About a third of the planes are "survivable" in the sense that the environment won't immediately kill you. If they clear that hurdle, the tricky part is surviving the inhabitants, and avoiding the hazards of travel (starvation, thirst, inconveniently-positioned pitfalls, etc.) while making the long trek back.
That being said, commoners could potentially make it back without much difficulty; the planescape setting is rife with portals, conduits, and vortices, so the biggest non-survival obstacle to to a planar commoner making it back is finding someone to ask for directions.

Walking off the edge and climbing down a wall are different things!  (The question title says climb, the question body talks about stepping off).  e.g. with spider climb, how far down can you go before you get ported?  Can you go around the "back" of the flattened-torus / ringworld, or just down onto the side at all to move along away from any buildings?  (If that's the only official source material describing what happens, is there any context that sheds light on what "border" they mean?  Like at street level, or past the "bottom" of the ring?)

@PeterCordes When I wrote the question I had two "models of gravity" in mind: in one, gravity works like centrifugal force, i.e. the edge is perceived like having gravity going outside. In another, the gravity always points to the mass of the torus, in which case you could simply walk across the edge, with gravity being kind of 45 degrees to it. In fact, in this case the "edge" wouldn't even be a special place at all, now that I think of it.

Where are the two characters in the foreground of the image standing? It looks like they are outside of the torus, looking up at the outer side of it. Shouldn't they be teleported away?

@NobodytheHobgoblin Maybe? It's possible the artist made an error. It's also possible that the artist assumed that the "teleported to another plane" thing only affects people who leave the torus, not those who approach it from the outside, and is imagining an adventure in which some canny bloods manage the latter, discovering a secret of the multiverse in the process.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Sigil exists in the plane of neutrality, the Outlands/Concordant Opposition, as a ring around the central spire. It's possible to climb that spire and look into Sigil from the outside, though you can't enter it that way, and of course once you're inside you can't leave that way either.

@NobodytheHobgoblin I don't know where exactly the image comes from, but I'm assuming they're not actually there, instead they have some sort of vision

@Glazius "Possible" is overstating it: the Spire is infinitely tall (or at least so tall that no being has ever managed to reach its top, but it's always described as infinitely tall) and no magic of any kind functions near it. Sigil also isn't around the Spire, it's at its top.
